# Group by "Removed" status on Azure devops dashboard

Tags: azure-devops

I have a requirement to create a dashboard using VSTS (azure devops) that gets me the trend of bugs that are removed (rejected). I tried to use the "Chart", Group By "State" and "Last Year" for the rolling period in the dashboard. It works fine for New, Approved and Committed. But it doesn't work for the Done and Removed. For Done and removed it returns the cumulative count. For e.g if 3 bugs are removed in Jan, 4 bugs removed in Feb and 3 bugs in March, it returns 3 for Jan, 7 for Feb and 10 for Mar in the chart. Is there anyway to get the actual counts instead of the cumulative counts. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual counts about the Done and Removed State, you can change your chart type to others, such like pie.

[image]

Then you will get the result as below.

[image]

The testquery1 is used to query all bugs.
[image]

Comment: But I want to get the trend i.e, the total count of "Removed" work items each month for the last one year. The Pie chart gives me the current distribution only.

Comment: The Chart is used to the toal count of the query. If you want to check the total count of "Removed" work items each month for the last one year, I recommand you to change the query condition.